# Set Specified region for Motion Detection

Tags: c#, emgucv

I need to specify a region on where motion detection will occur. What I am trying to do is count the number of vehicles that passes a certain region. Below is my code:

```
private static void ProcessFrame(Mat backgroundFrame, int threshold, int erodeIterations, int dilateIterations)
{
    // Find difference between background (first) frame and current frame
    CvInvoke.AbsDiff(backgroundFrame, rawFrame, diffFrame);

    // Apply binary threshold to grayscale image (white pixel will mark difference)
    CvInvoke.CvtColor(diffFrame, grayscaleDiffFrame, ColorConversion.Bgr2Gray);
    CvInvoke.Threshold(grayscaleDiffFrame, binaryDiffFrame, threshold, 255, ThresholdType.Binary);

    // Remove noise with opening operation (erosion followed by dilation)
    CvInvoke.Erode(binaryDiffFrame, denoisedDiffFrame, null, new Point(-1, -1), erodeIterations, BorderType.Default, new MCvScalar(1));
    CvInvoke.Dilate(denoisedDiffFrame, denoisedDiffFrame, null, new Point(-1, -1), dilateIterations, BorderType.Default, new MCvScalar(1));

    rawFrame.CopyTo(finalFrame);
    //Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(100, 100, 100, 100);
    //finalFrame = crop_color_frame(rawFrame, rec);
    var img = crop_color_frame(denoisedDiffFrame, rec);
    DetectObject(denoisedDiffFrame, finalFrame);
}

static int vnum = 0;
private static void DetectObject(Mat detectionFrame, Mat displayFrame)
{
    using (VectorOfVectorOfPoint contours = new VectorOfVectorOfPoint())
    {
        // Build list of contours
        CvInvoke.FindContours(detectionFrame, contours, null, RetrType.List, ChainApproxMethod.ChainApproxSimple);

        // Selecting largest contour
        if (contours.Size > 0)
        {
            double maxArea = 0;
            int chosen = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < contours.Size; i++)
            {
                VectorOfPoint contour = contours[i];

                double area = CvInvoke.ContourArea(contour);

                if (area > maxArea)
                {
                    maxArea = area;
                    chosen = i;
                }

            }

            // Draw on a frame
            MarkDetectedObject(displayFrame, contours[chosen], maxArea, contours.Size, maxArea);
        }
    }
}



private static void MarkDetectedObject(Mat frame, VectorOfPoint contour, double area, double contourSize, double maxArea)
        {
            // Getting minimal rectangle which contains the contour
            Rectangle box = CvInvoke.BoundingRectangle(contour);

            // Drawing contour and box around it
            CvInvoke.Polylines(frame, contour, true, drawingColor);
            CvInvoke.Rectangle(frame, box, drawingColor);

            // Write information next to marked object
            Point center = new Point(box.X + box.Width / 2, box.Y + box.Height / 2);
            Point center2 = new Point(box.Width, box.Height);

            var info = new string[] {
                $"Area: {area}",
                $"Position: {center.X}, {center.Y}"
            };
            Console.WriteLine($"X: {center.X} | Y: {center.Y} | Area: {area} | Count: {vnum} | Status: {vehicleState} | contour: {contour.Size}");



            switch (vehicleState)
            {
                case VehicleState.Entering:

                    if(_startCount)
                    {
                        //if(((maxArea > 15000 && maxArea <= 20000) && center.Y <= 120) || ((maxArea >= 5000 && maxArea < 10000) && center.Y >= 150))
                        if(center.Y >= 100 && maxArea > 20000)
                        {
                            CountVehicle();
                            vehicleState = VehicleState.Exiting;
                            _startCount = false;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case VehicleState.Exiting:
                    if (!_startCount)
                    {
                        //if(maxArea < 12000 && center.Y <= 120)
                        if(center.Y <= 130 && center.X <= 100 && maxArea <= 15000)
                        {
                            vehicleState = VehicleState.Entering;
                            _startCount = true;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }

            WriteMultilineText(frame, info, new Point(box.Right + 5, center.Y));
        }
```

As of the moment, this code works on detecting vehicles but I am just using the

> if(center.Y >= 100 && maxArea > 20000) condition to start counting the vehicles

the problem with that approach is, all movements in the frame are being monitored. That is why I need to set an specific region only.

Could you please show me how to do this?

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you mean by "I am just using the ... condition" ?

Comment: to start counting the vehicle, I use the if(center.Y >= 100 && maxArea > 2000) condition.

Comment: What's the problem now? You have any error?

Comment: I don't have error. I just need to know how to set the region where motion detection should happen.

Comment: You can limit the region for detection by setting ROI. Check my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set ROI for the input image

```
public static Mat crop_roi(Mat input_img)
{
    Image<Gray, byte> img = input_img.ToImage<Gray, byte>();
    double w = input_img.Width;
    double h = input_img.Height;
    Rectangle r = new Rectangle((int)(w * 0.2), (int)(h * 0.4), (int)(w * 0.6), (int)(h * 0.6));
    Image<Gray, byte> output = img.Copy(r);

    return output.Mat;
}

//USE
private static void DetectObject(Mat detectionFrame, Mat displayFrame)
{
    using (VectorOfVectorOfPoint contours = new VectorOfVectorOfPoint())
    { 
        //set roi to the frame
        Mat roi = new Mat()
        roi = set_roi(detectionFrame);

        // Build list of contours
        CvInvoke.FindContours(roi , contours, null, RetrType.List, ChainApproxMethod.ChainApproxSimple);

        // Selecting largest contour
        ...

        MarkDetectedObject(roi , contours[chosen], maxArea, contours.Size, maxArea);

 }
```

Below is the image I draw the ROI in an image, you can adjust the ROI by changing the parameter in this line `Rectangle r = new Rectangle((int)(w * 0.2), (int)(h * 0.4), (int)(w * 0.6), (int)(h * 0.6));`

[image]